# Processing an InputStream and writing to an OuputStream, and ensuring that both streams get closed

Tags: java, error-handling, io

Is it a bad thing to do multiple file closings in single finally block?

Relevant excerpt:

```
BufferedInputStream inStream;
BufferedOutputStream destStream;
try {
    inStream = new BufferedInputStream(/*...*/);
    destStream = new BufferedOutputStream(/*...*/);
    // ... reading from file
    // ... processing
    // ... writting to file
    destStream.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    try { destStream.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
    try { inStream.close(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
```

EDIT-1: I cant have java7 (so I can't use `try-with` from java7) :(

Comment: Java 6 is [no longer being updated publicly](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html). I don't suppose you enjoy paying for Oracle Premium Support for Java 6? Or are you using [IBM Java 6](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/lifecycle/)?

Comment: "Enjoy" is a word not related to my work. (changing tools used in organization is hard task, unless you own "gartner.com" email)

Answer (score 2):

As Nolequen wrote, his option is better to use. But it's [only possible in Java 7+](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

If you want to proceed with your solution you can create one try and put close inside.

```
    try {
        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(/*...*/);
        BufferedOutputStream destStream = new BufferedOutputStream(/*...*/);
        // ... reading from file
        // ... processing
        // ... writting to file
        destStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try { 
            destStream.close(); 
            inStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ignored) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use [try-with-resource](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjpk-7W98jSAhXHkSwKHaTNChwQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fessential%2Fexceptions%2FtryResourceClose.html&usg=AFQjCNFvZ4XSyiwfkKx3_YXW9HPmOMxZyw&sig2=leu85W7lO3f3OJYS60vaHg) statement. So you will not need to close streams manualy:

```
try (final BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(/*...*/);
     final BufferedOutputStream destStream = new BufferedOutputStream(/*...*/)) {
    //do some work
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: That definitely seems better in many ways, but it is java7 only. Right?

Comment: Yes, you right. Prior to Java 7, you can use a finally block with multiple close().

Answer (score 1):

Both, `InputStream` and `OutputStream` implement the `Closable` interface in Java6 so you can write your own exception ingnoring closer object/method:

```
private void closeIgnoringException(Closable closable){
     try { closable.close(); } 
     catch (Exception ignored) {
       ignored.printStacktrace();
     }
}

Set<Closable> closables = new HasSet<Closable>();  
try {
    BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(/*...*/);
    closables.add(inStream);
    BufferedOutputStream destStream = new BufferedOutputStream(/*...*/);
    closables.add(destStream );
    // ... reading from file
    // ... processing
    // ... writting to file
    destStream.flush();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log("ERROR: " + e.getMessage());
} finally {
    for(Closable closable : closables)
       closeIgnoringException(closable );
}
```